# Center Map to Bounds not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to center map to fit all markers.  There are lots of example of this, and seems reasonably easy, but I just can't get it to work.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The map can be tested here: http://www.lymphoedema.org.au/the-register/find-a-practitioner-test/ [[Search within 40kms of 3000; then click Map to view the map]].

The map is zoomed right out, and the markers are up in the very top left corner of the map.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var markers = [];
    var marker;

    console.log('About to setup map');

    //setup the map 
    function initialize() {

        var mapProp = {
          draggable: true,
          scrollwheel: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("resultmap-canvas"), mapProp);

        // show markers
        var myLatLng = {lat: -37.8757303, lng: 145.1277893};
        var marker6610 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });
        marker6610.setValues( {profileid: 6610, directoryid: 2} );
        markers.push(marker6610);

        var myLatLng = {lat: -38.0034790, lng: 145.1198805};
        var marker5316 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });
        marker5316.setValues( {profileid: 5316, directoryid: 2} );
        markers.push(marker5316);

        //set map bounds
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
           bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    }

    //execute the map creation
    initialize();

    // trigger map resize event when map tab is displayed
    $("#mapTab").on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });


</script>
```

Comment: We need to see your code in the question, not in an external link.

Comment: Thanks MrUpsidedown.. have added the JS code in question.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine when tested out of a bootstrap tab. So I guess the resize trigger has some implication in the issue.

Try this way:

Declare your `bounds` variable outside of the `initialize` function scope (that is where you define your `marker` and `markers` variables). By the way, you are missing the `map` variable declaration too.

```
var markers = [];
var marker;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map; // missing in your original code
```

Then fit the bounds too in the bootstrap shown event:

```
// trigger map resize event when map tab is displayed
$("#mapTab").on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.fitBounds(bounds); // add this line to your code
});
```

Don't forget to also remove the `var` declaration here:

```
//set map bounds
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Should now be:

```
//set map bounds
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

This is untested but that's all I can think of right now. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Nice work MrUpsidedown.  Moving the map.fitBounds() down into the tab trigger is what fixed it.  Thanks So Much!!  I've been stuck on this for days.  Cheers!!